# Calculate the limit of $\left(\frac{n+1}{n-5}\right)^{5n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}d_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n-5}\right)^{5n-2}$$
My problem probably because I think this limit it kind of $1^\infty$ limit and I know it's undefined.

Do I need to use this assumption to find this limit?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$

Comment: I prefer not to use it this moment because I didn't learn it yet in my college.
there is another way?

Comment: @AndrewLi L'Hopital is really overkill here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite
$$
\frac{n+1}{n-5} = 1+\frac{6}{n-5} 
$$
from which
$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n+1}{n-5}\right)^{5n-2}
&= \left(1+\frac{6}{n-5} \right)^{5n-2}
= \left(1+\frac{6}{n-5} \right)^{5(n-5)+23}\\
&= \left(\left(1+\frac{6}{n-5} \right)^{n-5}\right)^{5}\cdot \left(1+\frac{6}{n-5}\right)^{23}
\end{align}$$
Now, use the limit you know to show that the first factor will converge to $(e^{6})^5=e^{30}$; while the second is easily seen to converge to $1^{23}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify we can let $m=n-5\to \infty$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n-5}\right)^{5n-2}=\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\frac{m+6}{m}\right)^{5m+23}=\lim_{m \to \infty} \left[\left(1+\frac{6}{m}\right)^{m}\right]^{\frac{5m+23}{m}}=e^{30}$$